# Django annotate query with values from Many To Many Relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Following the example on Many To Many relationships for Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

I want to be able to display in the Django Admin a column on the Article listview which contains the title's of associated Publications.  So if I have an article `a1` which has publications:

```
Publication(title='Pub 1')
Publication(title='Pub 2')
```

I want to see a column in the admin listview showing `"Pub 1, Pub 2"`.  I could do this with a custom function on the Admin class:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['publication_titles']
    def publication_titles(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([pub.title for pub in obj.publications.all()])
```

But that's an N+1 problem: each Article row will execute a query for each associated publication.  I see this in the Django debug toolbar, where I see the number of SQL queries executed go from 9 queries to 33 when rendering 24 articles in the listview.

I thought maybe I could do `prefetch_related` in the queryset:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['publication_titles']
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset.prefetch_related('publications')
        return queryset

    def publication_titles(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([pub.title for pub in obj.publications.all()])
```

But that seems to have no effect on the number of SQL queries executed.

I thought I could use `annotate()` to annotate the queryset used in the admin, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do that.  Like I want to do something like:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['publication_titles']
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset.annotate(publication_titles=<HOW DO I GENERATE THE COLLECTION OF TITLES>)
        return queryset
```

But I'm not grokking what I'd put in place for `<HOW DO I GENERATE THE COLLECTION OF TITLES>`.

How can I get the list of Publications displayed without spiking the number of queries to the DB?

Comment: In case someone comes across the same question, you can use [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) together with [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset), to get each object of the queryset with its title.  

`from django.db.models import F
queryset.prefetch_related('publications').annotate(pub_title=F("publications__title"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QuerySet`s are immutable, this thus means that `.prefetch_related` creates a *new* `QuerySet`, you thus work with:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['publication_titles']
    
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('publications')

    def publication_titles(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([pub.title for pub in obj.publications.all()])
```